# Polynomial Function given roots and a point

Tags: polynomials

A 3rd degree polynomial has roots at x=-2i and x=5.  The y-intercept is (0,25).  Write an equation for this function in factored form with real coefficients.

My first hack is to say that in factored form this is (x-5)(X<sup>2</sup>+4) as that gets me the roots, but that has y-intercept (0,-20).  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Duh!  Thanks.  -2i was how the problem was written, but yeah, they come in pairs don't they...if you want to stick that in as an answer I'll gladly accept it

Comment: The way it states that the polynomial has real coefficients is a bit vague, but sure, then $-2i$ gives $+2i$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on SmileyCraft's answer (they give the answer but not the underlying reason *why*, which I feel is more important)...

---

**The Roots:**

On first contending with the roots issue, which the comments hint you had trouble with: we know $-2i$ and $5$ are roots. We know that since $-2i$ is a root, $+2i$ is also a root because it's the conjugate of $-2i$. Then, since $5, -2i, +2i$ are all roots, we know that the polynomial can be factored as

$$f(x) = a(x - 5)(x - 2i)(x + 2i)$$

up to a leading coefficient $a$ that I'll talk about later. (You assumed $a=1$, and I'll explain why that's wrong in the next section.) It should be clear that this form is correct otherwise, since plugging in any of our roots gives $f(x) = 0$.

Since you wanted real coefficients and such, we note that $(x-2i)(x+2i)=x^2 + 4$, thus giving us the form you posed in the question (again, up to that constant $a$).

---

**Finding $a$:**

So now you know that the polynomial has the form

$$f(x) = a(x-5)(x^2 + 4)$$

The reason we include this $a$ is because the leading coefficient of the polynomial doesn't actually affect the roots: it does affect certain aspects of its behavior, but not that one.

*(Note of import: that is only true when the polynomial is factored in this form. For example, in the other standard form of a cubic, $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, the coefficient $a$ **does** affect the zeroes. It's only if in this factored form that the leading coefficient does not affect the roots. Play around on a graphing calculator, shouldn't be hard to convince yourself of these facts.)*

We also know that the $y$-intercept of the graph is $(0,25)$. Thus, plug in $x = 0$ and $f(x) = 25$ in the equation above, and then you'll be able to figure out what $a$ actually is.

Plugging in these values, then, we see

$$25 = a(-5)(4) \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; 25 = a(-20) \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; a = \frac{25}{-20} = -\frac{5}{4}$$

Thus, the polynomial in its factored form is

$$f(x) = \left( -\frac{5}{4} \right)(x-5)(x^2 + 4)$$

Comment: In my defense, from the question I thought it was quite clear that jerH has a good idea of what he's doing, so I thought they should be able to understand why my answer is correct.

Comment: Yeah I suppose I can sort of see that. I don't think he actually did, though, seeing as he described his method as a hack. (I feel like he came up with the $(x-5)(x^2 + 4)$ more by trial and error than a more thorough process.) That was my big hint that a detailed answer would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You solve the problem by simply multiplying the polynomial by $\frac{25}{-20}$.